# AutoHotKey: can not write a variable value into a file

Tags: autohotkey

I am sure I am making a very simple mistake but I must be having a blonde day today. I can not figure it out.

Here is my situation:
I will take several values of input from the user using `InputBox`, as such:

```
InputBox, r, what is the value of r ?, Enter Value, , 400, 100, 300, 300, , 10, 1
InputBox, c, what is the value of c ?, Enter Value, , 420, 120, 300, 300, , 10, 3
InputBox, ct, what is the count ?, Enter Value, , 440, 140, 300, 300, , 10, 10
```

Then I will write these values into a file, so that, next time user hits the same hotkey combo, it will give him the option of using the same values used the last time.

So I thought I'd use something like this:

```
file := FileOpen( "c:\users\me\ahk.txt", "a" )
if !IsObject(file)
{
MsgBox Can't open "%FileName%" for writing.
return
}

str := "r_val="
file.Write(str)
str := %r%
file.write(str)
str := "`r`n
file.write(str)

; ... repeat for all variables

file.Close()
```

and repeat the last block for all variable values I want to record.

my problem is, the static strings are writing to the specified file one way or the other but not the wariables enclosed between % signs. I read the ahk help files quite a bit and thought I was following the examples to the "t". Yet, my result is not what I expected it to be.

I also tried closing the file after first write and then use

```
fileappend,
(
%mintmout%
),"c:\users\me\ahk.txt"
```

but that didn't help either.

Could someone please tell me what is wrong here and how to fix it ?

Also, if you can answer this additional question, which I am sure will come after I fixed the problem at hand.

My file will be something like :

```
r=5
c=7
ct=10
...
```

I will need to read from this file and assign the values to their respective variables. How do I accomplish this in ahk scripting ?

Thanks for answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `:=` for variable assignment, the `%` symbols are not needed.

The line

```
 str := %r%
```

Should be

```
str := r
```

Regarding your second question, if you need to write and retrieve values often I would recommend using [IniRead](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm) and [IniWrite](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniWrite.htm) instead of a simple text file.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I mean the value without enclosing t between % signs. I also tried iniwrite as follows: `IniWrite, %r%, "c:\users\me\myahk.ini", INIT, r_val` but nothing gets wrtitten into the file. I tried creating it beforehand and putting an [INIT] section with dummy values under it. Still nada. Any ideas on syntax of iniwrite/iniread commands ?

Comment: I personally use a separate [Ini Library](https://github.com/denolfe/AutoHotkey/blob/master/lib/Ini.ahk).  There are a few others out there which make working with ini files easier.

Comment: The issue with the code in your comment is the quotes around the file path.  Remove those, and it should work just fine.

Comment: thank you. that was it. Wondering what an additional ini library would get me as my needs are very basic

Comment: If all you need are Read and Write, there is no need. However, if you ever need to loop through the file, get all of the sections, or anything like that, a library would help. Also, if you could mark this as the answer, that would be great.